# How to POST retrofit return JSON with Root

Tags: android, post, retrofit

i have a problem to take json with root/parent

Web Service

```
@POST("login")
Call<LoginResponse> userLogin(@Body LoginRequest loginRequest);
```

My Model for Response

```
public class LoginResponse {
    @SerializedName("token")
    private String tokenLogin;
    @SerializedName("token_type")
    private String tokenType;
    @SerializedName("expires_in")
    private String expiresTime;
}
```

My call response:

```
  Call<LoginResponse> loginResponseCall = 
  ApiClient.getUserService().userLogin(loginRequest);
    loginResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                token = response.body().getTokenLogin().toString();
                String tokenType = response.body().getTokenType();
                String tokenExpire = response.body().getExpiresTime();
                userDao.addUser(new User(etUsername.getText().toString().trim(),etPassword.getText().toString().trim(),token));
}
```

It's work when my response is:

{
"token": "123456",
"token_type": "type",
"expire_in": "60"
}

But need take this response:
{
users:{
"token": "123456",
"token_type": "type",
"expire_in": "60"
}
}

What i need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have create a new class as named User becomes that parameter. Try this one

```
public class LoginResponse {
    @SerializedName("users")
    private User user;
}
```

Make an another model class.

```
public class User {
    @SerializedName("token")
    private String tokenLogin;
    @SerializedName("token_type")
    private String tokenType;
    @SerializedName("expires_in")
    private String expiresTime;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i understand logic, but how i need modify POST method and Call?

Comment: why do you need to modify POST method and Call? @AndrewS

Comment: I need for another method but, i have same problem where i called List: @POST("products")
 Call<List<ProductResponse>> products(@Body ProductRequest productRequest);
sorry if I didn't explain correctlyю

Comment: Have you tried the answer yet or not? @AndrewS

Comment: Yes, for this problem it's OK. Now i create another question. Thank you

Comment: I have create new question, if you can answer? this is same problem, but with List (Thanks):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68248634/how-to-post-retrofit-return-jsonarray-with-root