# How to POST retrofit return JSONArray with Root

Tags: android, post, retrofit

i have a problem to take json with root/parent

Web Service

```
@POST("products")
Call<List<ProductResponse>> products(@Body ProductRequest productRequest);
```

My Model for Response

```
public class ProductResponse{
   private String id_prodotto;

   private String nome_prodotto;
```

}
My call response:

```
  public void products(String s){
    ProductRequest productRequest = new ProductRequest();
    productRequest.setToken(s);
    Call <List<ProductResponse>> pR = 
   ApiClient.getUserService().products(productRequest);
    pR.enqueue(new Callback<List<ProductResponse>>() {
       @Override 
        public void onResponse(Call<List<ProductResponse>> call, retrofit2.Response<List<ProductResponse>> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                productList = response.body();
                recyclerViewProdotti.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
                recyclerViewProdotti.setHasFixedSize(true);
                adapterProducts = new AdapterProducts(context.getApplicationContext(),productList,tkn);
                recyclerViewProdotti.setAdapter(adapterProducts);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Fail Products " + tkn, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<ProductResponse>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("PR", t.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
```

It's work when my response is:

{ "id_prodotto": "1", "nome_prodotto": "one"}
{ "id_prodotto": "2", "nome_prodotto": "two"}

But need take this response: { products: { "id_prodotto": "1", "nome_prodotto": "one"}
{ "id_prodotto": "2", "nome_prodotto": "two"}}

What i need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `List<Object>` since your response is like. But you need to remove List at the Webservice.

```
@POST("products")
Call<ProductListResponse> products(@Body ProductRequest productRequest);
```

Next, at you need to create new model class named `ProductListResponse` with using List.

```
public class ProductListResponse {
    @SerializedName("products")
    private List<ProductResponse> product;
}
```